# Dataframe join in pandas on part of the String of Joining Columns

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have 2 Dataframes in pandas, I want to INNER join the 2 tables on `JoinColumn`,But Values in `Table1.JoinColumn` is like `1_String1_0` and in the `Table2.JoinColumn` is like `2_String1_1`, What is possible way to join both tables without splitting the column values by "_" and join later.

```
Table1= pd.DataFrame({'JoinColumn' : pd.Series(['1_Abc_0','2_Cde_1','3_Efg_0','5_xyz_1'], index=['a', 'b', 'c','d']), 'Col2' : pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),'Col3' : pd.Series([1, 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])})

Table2= pd.DataFrame({'JoinColumn' : pd.Series(['2_Abc_1','2_Cde_0','6_Efg_0','9_xyz_2'], index=['a', 'b', 'c','d']), 'Col2' : pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),'Col3' : pd.Series([1, 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])})
```

I want to merge these two tables on `JoinColumn` considering on values like "Abc","xyz" etc..

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: @jezrael updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is necessary split, but `Series` should be input of `left_on` and `right_on` parameters:

```
df = pd.merge(Table1, 
              Table2, 
              left_on=Table1['JoinColumn'].str.split('_').str[1],
              right_on=Table2['JoinColumn'].str.split('_').str[1])

print (df)
   Col2_x  Col3_x JoinColumn_x  Col2_y  Col3_y JoinColumn_y
0      10     1.0      1_Abc_0      10     1.0      2_Abc_1
1      20     2.0      2_Cde_1      20     2.0      2_Cde_0
2      30     3.0      3_Efg_0      30     3.0      6_Efg_0
3      40     4.0      5_xyz_1      40     4.0      9_xyz_2
```

Comment: Ok, I was expecting something like this, Thanks jez